# Why can't I import the GoogleSignInClient class?

Tags: java, android, api

I'm trying to use google silent sign-in, but the GoogleSignInClient class is not defined for some reason. When I alt-enter, it just says "create class" not import class. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

[image]

```
private void signInSilently() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                        GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                    } else {
                        // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    signInSilently();
}
```

Also:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
```

Comment: your error says simply Class Not Found. make sure you implement that package

Comment: Yes that could be the problem, but I am not sure which package I am missing in the dependencies, or how to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by updating the file

> build.gradle (Project: projectname)

in this specific part

from:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

with:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'